# library not found for -lPods after added GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, admob, lpod

This is my `pod`file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App FM' do # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks

# use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  # Pods for App FM


end
```

but I'm getting this error when I build the project.

**ld: library not found for -lPods-App FM
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

And I have opened the workspace file not the proj file

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C ? Also I have never seen `dynamic frameworks` what is that ?

Comment: Im using onjective_c

Comment: Im not sure what is that. It came when I added google admob sdk

Comment: try to remove your `podfile.lock` and `pods` directory , then remove `dynamic frameworks` line in your podfile then do a `pod install`  lets see what happens

Comment: Sorry that line was commented one. And I re installed it. but still Im getting the error :( no luck

Answer (score 0):

First go to your App FM target in your workplace `Project -> App FM -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` check if your have Pods-App FM.framework is added.

Also long shot but you should make your target name `AppFM` not `App FM`, this is a bit work but that space in your Target name might be throwing the cocoapods off.

Your appname still can be App FM but choosing a target name with a space is not a good practice. Change it to AppFM